# Export more than one page html to single pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, pdf

I have a little project built in php/javascript which every page are split in two parts. On left side a list of href, for example

```
<a href="index.php?id=1>page 1</a>
<a href="index.php?id=2>page 2</a>
<a href="index.php?id=3>page 3</a>
```

then on right side some code block that load info from xml file (file1.xml, fil2.xml, file3.xml) depending on id of url

Now I need to create a button at the end of left list that create a single PDF of all this page

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DOMPDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwihjuDQrvvIAhUHZCYKHfUSAGw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdompdf%2Fdompdf&usg=AFQjCNHWbqR_M4vc5HMdaJrlhvvIlxq9gA&sig2=27072cK39O4lch2SKrC-9w) to generate PDF from HTML. So what you can do is you can write a PHP script that grabs all data from those pages, combine it in one HTML code and convert to PDF using DOMPDF.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to do this:

(1) convert your html pages to PDF 'online' using [web2pdfconvert](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/) , [htmlpdf](http://www.htmlpdf.com/) or [pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/)

(2) then put the PDF file on your server

(3) create a button, that when you click it will download the PDF file